# Creating a django model for a completely different set of users

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a model called `Driver`, which isn't inheriting from the in-built User model every django project comes with. Another model I created inherits from it. Each driver has a name, email and phone number. The model doesn't inherit the `set_password()` or `check_password()` functions from the User model so I had to make some additions to the model to save the hashed password. However, any time I test a login, it doesn't work, on account of the typed password not matching the hash in the database.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Hash the password before saving
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
   
    def check_password(self, password):
        return self.password == password
```

How can I create a function to properly compare the typed passwords to the hashed version in the database? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This check is incorrect

```
def check_password(self, password):
    return self.password == password
```

as you check raw password with hashed on. When you do

```
make_password(self.password)
```

It hashes password.

So you need to compare:

```
return self.password == make_password(password)
```

But I urge you to use Django build in functionality.

Comment: How would I go about that?